# How to recycle 'threading.Thread' objects in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I was wondering how you would recycle 'threading.Thread' objects in python?

Firstly, I create (x) amount of threads("workers") and store within a list.
I start them as usual and join them once they've finished.
Then I file data from data gathered from a shared object.
Finally, I clear all threads("workers") within the list and repeat this cycle within a conditional loop.

The problem I seem to be having is that the thread objects still exist even after removing them. Say I use 10 threads, the next time it cycles through I end up using thread 11-20.

Is there a way to terminate the the first cycle of threads after joining and effectively recycle the same threads?

Kind regards,

Andrew

Comment: Thread IDs are not dense sequences: what leads to the assertion of “using thread 11-20” and “[thread objects] still exist”? (A thread is finished — and `is_alive` is reset to False —when it’s `run` method terminates. Without a timeout, a `join` is guaranteed to wait for this condition and the thread is “no longer alive” and the actual Python thread *wrapper* object follows normal lifetime (and GC) rules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to terminate the the first cycle of threads after joining" - joining is the same as terminating, though. `the_thread.name` looks like `'Thread-N'`, where `N` is the "number" of a thread, which is normally increased for each new thread. This doesn't necessarily mean that if this thread is `'Thread-100'`, then the previous 99 threads are still running.

Joining a thread means terminating it, so no stray threads will be left running.

### Example

```
>>> import threading, time
>>> th = threading.Thread(target=lambda: time.sleep(10))
>>> th.start(); th.join()
>>> th.is_alive()
False # the thread is dead
>>> th.name
'Thread-1'
>>> th2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: time.sleep(10))
>>> th2.start(); th2.join()
>>> th2.is_alive(), th2.name
(False, 'Thread-2') # This thread is dead alongside Thread-1
>>>
```

You can test it by looking at how many threads your Python process has (in Task manager or maybe something like `top`):

1. Create a thread that just hangs there for some time:

   ```
   th = threading.Thread(target=lambda: time.sleep(10))
   ```
2. Start the thread and wait for it: `th.start(); th.join()`
3. While the thread is running, quickly locate *the Python process* in Task manager
4. It should have 2 OS threads running (Python actually creates OS threads for each running `threading.Thread`!)
5. Once the thread exits, the Python process will have only one OS thread - the main interpreter thread.
6. Thus, the thread you created terminated.